# $_POST in php is empty when data is too big

Tags: php, post

We have developed a web application using php. It worked perfectly until the client migrated it to VMware. Ever since some of the forms which were sent in POST are not being sent and we found out that it only happens when above a certain amount of data is being sent.
It only happens when running the application in the VMware environment.

HELP please!!

UPDATE:
In the apache_error.log file I found the following error:
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0, referer: .....

This param could only be found in the php.ini-development and php.ini-production and it was commented so I've removed the ;; and increased the value and also added the value in the php.ini file but it all being ignored as I can see in the phpinfo()
any suggestion?

PHP version 5.3.13

Comment: How big is too big? Is VMware running the web application, or is it just hosting the virtual machine that runs the web application?

Comment: If there just isn't enough memory, then that is that. Check the error.log, we can't. Also `post_max_size` in the php.ini etc.

Comment: I found out that in the apache_error.log there is an error: "
Input variables exceeded 1000 so need to change the max_input_vars in php.ini. Well - I did but it was commented so that's mean it was ignored? also it doesn't exists in the php.ini just in production and development so where is the right location?

Comment: @coder543 - it is the hosting machine. Any suggestion which configuration should I change?

Answer (score 1):

The `max_input_vars` being commented in php.ini most likely means it is using the default value. You are able to override it by uncommenting it. Commented does not mean ignored in this case.

the `post_max_size` parameter should also be configurable inside your php.ini file. Make sure to restart apache before testing and after changing anything in that file. In your php.ini file, find the line that says

```
post_max_size = 2M
```

(or whatever max size)

and increase it to 8M or something similar.

Your php.ini file may or may not be located at

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

It really varies from distro to distro.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of  `post_max_size` in php.ini to `post_max_size = 2M`

or via .htaccesss add this

```
php post_max_size = 2M
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by increasing the value of max_input_vars in the php.ini file.
This worth knowing that one of the symptoms was that the POST array was empty...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a distribution configured to handle a

```
post_max_size
```

that is higher than the standard 2MB and you are sending "more" than 2MB.

You can override this using a custom php.ini or custom "php_value post_max_size 8MB" depending on the server configuration.

Comment: Where do you find this param? I cannot find it in the php.ini file. Is it server side?

Comment: Either you'll find it in the php.ini for your server or a custom php.ini file that you can define on your site (if the apache configuration supports it) or you'll find it in the Apache configuration, virtual host configuration or custom HTAccess file for your site/folder (Again largely depends on your hosting provider's configuration)